# Inconsistent definitions of Entropy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, definition

On the wikipedia page "Entropy", entropy is defined as $S=k_B \ln\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is "the number of microstates whose energy equals the system's energy". This is what I had always understood $\Omega$ to mean.

However, on the wikipedia page "Equipartition theorem", entropy is defined as $S=k_B \ln\Omega(E)$ where
$$\Omega(E)=\int_{H<E}d\Gamma$$
In other words, $\Omega(E)$ is the volume of phase space with energy ***less*** than $E$, not with energy ***equal*** to $E$. This definition is then used to derive the equipartition theorem.

Which entropy definition is correct? Is the derivation of the equipartition theorem on wikipedia incorrect?